# Why there is a problem if there is an empty stack (java)

Tags: java

(leetCode #20)
Coding Question : Given a string s containing just the characters '(', ')', '{', '}', '[' and ']', determine if the input string is valid.

An input string is valid if:

1. Open brackets must be closed by the same type of brackets.
2. Open brackets must be closed in the correct order.

Now here is the answer to this coding question.

```
class Solution {
public boolean isValid(String s) {
   Stack <Character> stack = new Stack <Character>();

    for (char c: s.toCharArray()) {
        if (c == '(' || c == '{' || c == '[') {
            stack.push(c);
        }
        else if (c == ')' && !stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek() == '(') {
            stack.pop();
        }
        else if (c == '}' && !stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek() == '{') {
            stack.pop();
    }
        else if (c == ']' && !stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek() == '[') {
            stack.pop();
        }
        else return false;
        
    }
    return stack.isEmpty();
}
}
```

I am a bit confused that what is the purpose of the "!stack.isEmpty()"? If I erase them, and put "]" for it put, it throws an runtime error which said "java.util.EmptyStackException".
Can anyone clarify this? I learned the stack today, so I am bit confused.

Comment: So you wonder what the purpose a statement is and when you remove the statement it results in exceptions, but you **didn't** conclude that the purpose of the statement was to prevent those exceptions?

Comment: You can't `peek` is stack is empty

Comment: ``!stack.isEmpty()`` is true (because of the ``!``) when the stack is not empty. If the stack is empty when you have a closing character, you can't use peek(), plus the string is invalid.

Answer (score 3):

`Stack#peek` looks at the top-most element and returns its value. If there is no top-most element (i.e. the stack is empty) it will throw an `EmptyStackException`. That is why you check if it is empty before peeking.

See the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#peek())

Comment: Thank you. So, rather than throwing false, it would throw the exception error?

Comment: `false` cannot be thrown it can only be returned. Exceptions are thrown. The method `peek` returns the top-most element throws an exception if there are no elements in the stack.

Comment: @hellowldmaz please mark as accepted answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

As the exception saying you are operating an empty stack which should not be empty. If you can post more error message, I think can locate to the line of `"stack.peek()"` that causes the error.

**&&** is Short-circuit operator, which means if `!stack.isEmpty()` is false, then `stack.peek()` won't be executed. so that make sure only the stack is not empty, then you can peek and pop it.

Comment: You are answering a different question. OP asks why `peek` throws when stack is empty.

Comment: @DogaOruc yes, I am editing the answer to tell more now

Comment: @DogaOruc he is asking the purpose of the condiction